# Open Shell within Python Subprocess

Tags: python-3.x

I have a script that opens a new shell with different conditions than the standard shell, let's call it `./new_shell <arg>`. I need to run `./new_shell <arg>` in a Python script, then run commands within that shell, then exit the shell and continue executing my script as usual. How can I do this?

The goal, in pseudo code, for reference:

```
for arg in args:
    subprocess.run(['./new_shell ' + arg], shell=True) #this doesn't behave as I want, because I need the shell to be automated, not manual
    subprocess.run([<various scripts that need to be run within new_shell])
    subprocess.run([<exit_shell>]) #don't know how to do this
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: You instead want to use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), then use [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to interact with that process.  You should really read the whole documentation for the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Thank you! I read through it and this is definitely what I want. I can't seem to get it to work, unfortunately /:

Comment: I suspect you want to essentially open a `bash` shell and then do a bunch of commands in it, then close it again?  You might want to consider just using Python to kick off all those processes and manage their interactions.   Could you share what you're trying to do specifically, or at least a representative example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use `Popen` as follows:

```
for arg in args:
    pro = subprocess.Popen(['new_shell', arg],
                           stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    inpt = <script_to_be_run_in_shell> + <arguments> +'\n'
    out, err = pro.communicate(inpt.encode())
```